# The girl deserves your attention more than he/him

Tags: pronouns

Which one is appropriate? **he** or **him** ?

I think there are two acceptable answers:

> The girl deserves your attention more than **him**.
>
> The girl deserves your attention more than **he does**.

Comment: You're quite right. They're both fine, and there's no reason to suppose one is more "appropriate" than the other.

Comment: We probably already have a post somewhere saying *than* can be either a preposition or a conjunction (in traditional terms).  I'm not sure where it is, though.

Answer (score 2):

They are both fine, but (at least to me) have very different meanings.

In "him" version the contrast is between "your attention" and "him". The girl deserves him, but she deserves your attention more.

In "he" version the contrast is between "girl" and "him". He deserves your attention, but the girl deserves it more.